# Multiple select after grouping in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

Multiple select after grouping in Linq Query

```
listItems = feeditem.Select(o => new 
                                { 
                                  MerchantName = o.MerchantName,
                                  ProductName= o.ProductName, 
                                  TT = o.TotalTransactions 
                                }).GroupBy(fl => fl.MerchantName).ToList()
                                  .Select(fl => new MerchantPerformanceAffiliate 
                                 { 
                                   MerchantName = fl.Key, 
                                   TotalTransactions = fl.Sum(x => x.TT)
                                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: What is your question..? Any source code??

Comment: The above  list return 2 column but i want 3 column after grouping.

MerchantName,
ProductName, 
Sum(TotalTransactions)

Comment: Then you want to GroupBy the merchant name and product name? Or just pick *a* product? i.e. the `First` product?

Comment: I want to group by only merchant name

Comment: Check my answer, u need include ProductName as well in group by clause.

Comment: I find it very to understand what you actually want. Could you include example input and output. Specifically, what should the result be when multiple items with different `ProductName`s have the same `MerchantName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:-

```
var query = from feed in feedItems
                         group feed by new { feed.MerchantName, feed.ProductName } into feedGroup
                         select new MerchantPerformanceAffiliate 
                         {
                             MerchantName = feedGroup.Key.MerchantName,
                             ProductName = feedGroup.Key.ProductName,
                             TotalTransactions = feedGroup.Sum(x => x.TotalTransactions)
                         };
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dm6OAk).

Here is the Method Syntax code (just in case):-

```
 var query2 = feedItems.GroupBy(feed => new { feed.MerchantName , feed.ProductName })
                                  .Select(items => new MerchantPerformanceAffiliate 
                                                                {
                                                                    MerchantName = items.Key.MerchantName,
                                                                    ProductName = items.Key.ProductName,
                                                                    TotalTransactions = items.Sum(x => x.TotalTransactions)
                                                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: @ARABINDASATAPATHY - Please check, i have updated both query syntax & method syntax codes. You can test same in .net Fiddle too.